# React-native expo FileSystem.downloadAsync corrupted images

Tags: reactjs, react-native, filesystems, expo

We have RN app and server to store images.

Trying to download bunch images from the server according to the user, and display them in RN application.

Sometimes the images will be corrupted, or not displayed at all so i have to reload the application for it to work (this will not even work a lot of the time), or to clear the storage and download the images again and again.

This one of the functions to download:

```
  downloadItemsImgs = async() => {
const {items, u_clname} = this.state

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(items)) {
  let imgPath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + value.item_img;
  let imgName = value.item_img;

  await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(imgPath).then(file => {
    if (file.exists === false) {

      try {
          FileSystem.downloadAsync(
          'https://servernamehere.com/uploads/' + u_clname +'/' + imgName, imgPath
        )
      }
      catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    }
  })
}
 }
```

and this is the out function:

```
outPutItems = (id) => {
let fileSystemPath = FileSystem.documentDirectory;
let output = [];
const {items} = this.state
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(items)) {

  if (value.group_id === id) {
    output.push(
      <Card 
        style={styles.itemCard}
        key={value.item_id}
      >
          <CardItem 
            cardBody
            button
            activeOpacity={0.5} 
            onPress={() => {
              this.goOneItem(value.item_id, value.item_name, value.group_id);
            }}
          >
            <ImageBackground 
              source={{uri: `${fileSystemPath}${value.item_img}`}} 
              style={{height: 250, width: null, flex: 1}}
            >
              <View style={[styles.itemTextContainer, {flexDirection: "column"}]}>
                <View style={[styles.itemPriceText]}>
                  <Text style={styles.itemText}>{value.item_name}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center", width: "100%", padding: 4,}}>
                  <Text style={styles.priceText}>{value.item_price} AED</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </ImageBackground>
          </CardItem>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}
return output;
}
```

Note: i tried to download in couple of networks (i thought it might be a network related issue), but still the same issue.

It's taking a long time for me to figure out where the issue is, is it from the download functions or the output!!?

Comment: Are you sure that the images stored in the server are not corrupt?